# Perform click on newly opened Activity

Tags: android, automation, instrumentation, robotium

I have written application which opens Settings Activity when we run it.

Is it possible to write  test application  for above application which should perform button clicks on Settings Activity?

I think it is possible with robotium and instrumentation.

Correct me if i am wrong .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) to do blackbox GUI testing. Check out this [example](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/11/test-driving-android-gui.html) or [this](http://testdroid.com/tech/54/automated-ui-testing-android-applications-robotium).

Comment: I tried with robotium ,test application is able to open Settings activity but unable to click on text.